# Что только что случилось с SO?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, stackexchange

Минуту назад у меня были недоступны все сайты сети SO. Стандартное сообщение.

> [image: stack overflow]

Вопрос - это только у меня проблемы, или это плановые работы, или это мини сбой?

Comment: спокойствие :-) дело-то житейское :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>Вы стали жертвой хакерских атак.</strike>

Это было обновление SO. Если бы вы зашли на enSO, то у вас бы высветилось, что он временно недоступен и обновляется. Так что не пугайтесь, если что.